# Change black listed functions in PyLint

Tags: python, pylint

I can disable the following warning completely:

> W0141: Used builtin function %r Used when a black listed builtin function is used (see the bad-function option). Usual black listed functions are the ones like map, or filter , where Python offers now some cleaner alternative like list comprehension.

But is there also a way to remove one function from the black list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a rc file for pylint. (See [pylint doc](http://docs.pylint.org/tutorial.html#getting-started) how to do this)

Within that you'll find something like this:

```
bad-functions=map,filter,apply,input
```

There you can simply remove the annoying function. If you're using Eclispe go afterwards to PyLint's preferences and add --rcfile=path\to\your_rc_file in the arguments for pylint input box.

Comment: you may also use the option on the command line, eg `--bad-functions=map,filter,etc`

Comment: @kitty In python 2, `input` will evaluate python code.  `raw_input` should be used instead.  In python 3, using input is equivalent to raw_input, so using input isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just listen to Pylint and get rid of the offending *usage* of that black listed function using a cleaner alternative such as list comprehension.

Comment: That won't be possible. The problem is the usage of input, and the code is written by students.